# React minified error #321 when trying to load external script

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to load an external script that must be loaded after the HTML element is rendered. For examples sake this is the code (the setTimeout purely for testing):

```
    const loadScript = async () => {

        const script = document.createElement('script')
        script.async = true
        console.log('loading')

        script.src = 'https://widgets.sportmonks.com/js/team/nextFixture.js'
        document.body.appendChild(script)
    };

    useEffect(() => {


        if (window && document) {
            try {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    loadScript()
                }, 5000)

            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e, 'error')
            }
        }
    }, [])
```

When loadScript() runs, upon appending the script to the dom I get the minified react error #321: **Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.** The error is thrown from a line inside of the external script.****

I have experimented with different timeouts and orders of loading but the same issue persists. I have verified that no duplication of react versions is present.

EDIT:

It seams as if the external script has a function called useState which is causing the error to flag, not sure how to get around that?

Comment: Add this script into `index.html`

Comment: @KannuMandora doing this causes an error in the script as the script loads before the div element that utilises the script is loaded into the dom.

Comment: use `defer` attribute to delay the script loading after the DOM rendered